# Can someone show me how I can let a member add their own tags to a question using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

What I mean is that I want logged in members to add their own tags to any given question they see fit. So far, I have got the following script that calls the tags entered into the database which is below.

```
<?php

function tag_info() {
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tags GROUP BY tag ORDER BY count DESC");
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $arr[$row['tag']] = $row['count'];
  }
```

Comment: Business logic, application logic and presentation in one file? Yikes! I'm not touching that.

Comment: Could you please clean up the code a bit - just some formatting, post it in a code block, and maybe clean up the last statement? It's a little hard to read this way.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you've put here, it sounds like your database schema needs some love. I recommend looking at [this article](http://www.pui.ch/phred/archives/2005/06/tagsystems-performance-tests.html), which addresses a number of the most common 'tag schemas' and their benefits, drawbacks, and performance characteristics.